# I am having issue building my first flutter app with android studio getting few errors can someone help me?

Tags: java, android, flutter, android-studio, gradle

Building with sound null safety

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\WordpressApp\main_files\source\wordpress_app\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                         2,412ms
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

- I am using following tools for flutter app development *
  Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1
  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683, built on May 18, 2022
  Runtime version: 11.0.12+7-b1504.28-7817840 amd64
  VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
  Windows 10 10.0
  GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
  Memory: 1536M
  Cores: 4
  Registry: external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
  Non-Bundled Plugins: org.jetbrains.intellij.scripting-javascript (1.0), com.intellij.javafx (1.0.4), org.jetbrains.kotlin (212-1.6.21-release-334-AS5457.46), Dart (212.5744), idea.plugin.protoeditor (212.5080.8), io.flutter (68.1.2)

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: can you please share the content of build.gradle file

Comment: please edit your question and  add the build.gradle content not in the comment

Comment: Having Added the Content in Question Please Check.

Comment: @Dhanveersing Please upload build.gradle (Module: xxx.app). (the other build.gradle file), the error occurs in that one.

Answer (score 0):

hello i think the problem that you have 2 subprojects block try to delete one and the  other like this :

```
rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check android/app/build.gradle

and see if this is existing there.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```